# Why is LUA_PATH containing a bang (!) mangled on Windows?

Tags: windows, lua

I have a file `main.lua`:

```
require("hello")
```

and a file `hello.lua` in the directory `foo bar! baz` (with `!`) in it:

```
module(...,package.seeall)
print("hello from hello.lua")
```

when I set (on Windows) the environment variable `LUA_PATH` to the directory:

```
set LUA_PATH="C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\foo bar! baz\?.lua"
```

I get a strange error:

```
C:\Programme\Lua\5.1>lua main.lua
lua: main.lua:4: module 'hello' not found:
        no field package.preload['hello']
        no file '"C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\foo barC:\Programme\Lua\5.1 baz\hello.lua
"'
        no file '.\hello.dll'
        no file '.\hello51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\hello.dll'
        no file 'C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\hello51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\clibs\hello.dll'
        no file 'C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\clibs\hello51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\loadall.dll'
        no file 'C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\clibs\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        main.lua:4: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

See the very strange path `C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\foo barC:\Programme\Lua\5.1 baz\hello.lua`? What is so special about the exclamation mark (bang)? How to get that right in windows? On Mac this seems to be working fine.

Comment: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-08/msg00052.html ?

Comment: @TheZ yes, exactly, many thanks! Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: Another reason to stick with punctuation free, ASCII only directory names ...

Comment: @jpjacobs what a very constructive command :) I've never thought of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "This substitution only happens the first time Lua sets the path
>   (either from `LUA_PATH` or from the default from luaconf). If you
>   set the path by other means, you can avoid the problem."

More info and potential alternatives: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-08/msg00052.html

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is correct (it's documented behavior on Windows), but I can also offer a possible solution (or rather a workaround): since only the first exclamation mark is going to be replaced, instead of using `set LUA_PATH="C:\Programme\Lua\5.1\foo bar! baz\?.lua"`, use:

```
set LUA_PATH="!\foo bar! baz\?.lua"
```